# Deploy Django app to Python Anywhere through GitHub

Tags: python, django, github, pythonanywhere, github-webhook

I am currently trying to set up a deployment pipeline for my django app to python anywhere.

But the github webhook recieves a 301 and I don't understand why...
"Last delivery was not successful. Invalid HTTP Response: 301"

I followed the instructions from this tutorial:
https://digitalshyna.com/blog/how-to-deploy-django-apps-to-python-anywhere-through-github/

I added the update url:

```
path('update_server/', views.update, name='update'),
```

this is my update view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def update(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    try:
        # Log the incoming request
        logger = logging.getLogger('webhook_logger')
        logger.info("Webhook POST request received")

        # Perform the code update
        repo = git.Repo('mayapp.pythonanywhere.com')
        origin = repo.remotes.origin
        origin.pull()

        # Log a success message
        message = "Updated code on PythonAnywhere"
        logger.info(message)

        return HttpResponse(message)
    except GitCommandError as e:
        # Log a Git error and return an error response
        error_message = f"Git Error: {str(e)}"
        logger.error(error_message)
        return HttpResponseServerError(error_message, status=500)
else:
    return HttpResponse("Couldn't update the code on PythonAnywhere")
```

GitPython is installed in my Pythonanywhere virtualenv.

I created the deploy key and added it to my repository on github. I created a second ssh-key and added it to my github account, I added both keys to the ssh-agend on pythonanywhere.
https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

When I access the route directly with Postman I see "Couldn't update the code on PythonAnywhere"
Status Code 200 OK

My log files remain empty I am not sure whats the problem yet but I will post the logs once working...

EDIT:

here is the logging configuration from my settings.py

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'error.log'),
        },
        'webhook_logger_file': { 
            'level': 'DEBUG', 
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'logs', 'webhook.log'), 
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'webhook_logger': {  
            'handlers': ['webhook_logger_file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG', 
            'propagate': False, 
        },
    },
}
```

the log files are getting created inside the logs directory but remain empty...

Comment: Where is your `webhook_logger` configured to write to?

Comment: @GilesThomas
It's configured to write to the logs folder inside of the base directory of my project. I added the logging configuration to my Post.
Logging is not working on either my machine or on pythonanywhere.

Comment: I think it would be a good plan to try to break this into two problems, then -- firstly, fixing the webhook, and secondly fixing the logging config.  I'd suggest removing the logging config entirely, and also the try/except in the webhook. Django's default logging setup will return a 500 error and put the traceback in the error log (the one you can access from the "Web" page inside PythonAnywere) if an exception is raised, so then you should be able to get more info about what's going wrong there.  The logging config perhaps could be a separate Stack Overflow question.